# Distance Metric different units

Tags: geometry, distance, euclidean-distance

I am trying to cluster a radar database. The observations of a radar are given in Azimuth angle and range. For processing speed reasons I do not want to transform this polar data into a Cartesian system.

A normal Euclidean distance metric needs the same unit in x- and y-direction. I need to find the distance in azimuth direction and in range direction. Basically, you can imagine the Euclidean distance metric working in a circle and my solution should work in an ellipse.

A simple solution to the problem is in the attached image the red example. 
[Sketech of ellipse radius](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvcVV.png)
I take from a centre point the distance in both directions.

I am searching for a solution that is more advanced like the blue example where I have all the points in an elliptical search.

EDIT:

I asked the same question a bit different formulated in the mathematics forum, maybe that helps you to understand my problem better. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3635438/epsilon-neighbourhood-for-polar-data

Comment: This is not about metrics.

Comment: Ok, can you tell me what it is about, then I can adjust my question.

Comment: Just hover over the tag or click on it..

Comment: Why is that tag wrong? The wiki definition of metric: In mathematics, a metric or distance function is a function that defines a distance between each pair of elements of a set.

Comment: Hover over the tag and read it!